# Updating multiple objects with ember-data and non-rest action

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Lets say I have a **Customer** who hasMany **products**

The api has a **PUT: /customers/:id/cancel** that cancels the customer and also cancels all the products and then returns the customer and the products for sideloading:

```
{
  customer: {
    id: 1,
    name: "Customer Name",
    canceled: true,
    products: [1, 2] },

  products: [
    {id: 1, customer_id: 1, name: "Product 1", canceled: true},
    {id: 2, customer_id: 1, name: "Product 2", canceled: true}
  ]
}
```

how would I:

1. Call that action on the customer?
2. Update all objects in the Ember Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part 1. of your question,

- You'll want to find it in the store `var customer = store.find('customer', 1);`
- Then tell it to delete `customer.destroyRecord();`
- And finally commit the delete `customer.save();`

For part 2. deleting the products, you'll have to do delete them manually in a forEach loop, tucked inside an `Ember.run.once`., as there is no cascading delete in ember data at this stage of the game.

Here is an example of this for a top level delete, so you would need to follow the same logic but for your `products` and follow it up with a [`.then`](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/asynchronous-routing/) that deletes your connected customer.

- Single tier Example: http://jsbin.com/samegiqe/1/edit?js,output
- Connected StackOverflow for further reading: [How to delete all records associated with an ember model without clearing local Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257758/how-to-delete-all-records-associated-with-an-ember-model-without-clearing-local)
- Complex mixin to solve this: http://jsbin.com/hupabovo/1/edit
- Its connected StackOverflow: [Delete associated model with ember-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177723/delete-associated-model-with-ember-data)

Hope that gets at what you were asking. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for answering this very old question, probably someone will find it useful when googling :)