# Delete associated model with ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two models:

```
App.User = DS.Model.create({
  comments: DS.hasMany('App.Comment')
});

App.Comment = DS.Model.create({
  user: DS.belongsTo('App.User')
});
```

When a user is deleted, it also will delete all its comments on the backend, so I should delete them from the client-side identity map.

I'm listing all the comments on the system from another place, so after deleting a user it would just crash.

Is there any way to specify this kind of dependency on the association? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use a mixin when I want to implement this behaviour. My models are defined as follows:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend(App.DeletesDependentRelationships, {
    dependentRelationships: ['comments'],

    comments: DS.hasMany('App.Comment'),
    author: DS.belongsTo('App.User')
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend();

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
    post: DS.belongsTo('App.Post')
});
```

The mixin itself:

```
App.DeletesDependentRelationships = Ember.Mixin.create({

    // an array of relationship names to delete
    dependentRelationships: null,

    // set to 'delete' or 'unload' depending on whether or not you want
    // to actually send the deletions to the server
    deleteMethod: 'unload', 

    deleteRecord: function() {
        var transaction = this.get('store').transaction();
        transaction.add(this);
        this.deleteDependentRelationships(transaction);
        this._super();
    },

    deleteDependentRelationships: function(transaction) {
        var self = this;
        var klass = Ember.get(this.constructor.toString());
        var fields = Ember.get(klass, 'fields');

        this.get('dependentRelationships').forEach(function(name) {
            var relationshipType = fields.get(name);
            switch(relationshipType) {
                case 'belongsTo': return self.deleteBelongsToRelationship(name, transaction);
                case 'hasMany': return self.deleteHasManyRelationship(name, transaction);
            }
        });
    },

    deleteBelongsToRelationship: function(name, transaction) {
        var record = this.get(name);
        if (record) this.deleteOrUnloadRecord(record, transaction);
    },

    deleteHasManyRelationship: function(key, transaction) {
        var self = this;

        // deleting from a RecordArray doesn't play well with forEach, 
        // so convert to a normal array first
        this.get(key).toArray().forEach(function(record) {
            self.deleteOrUnloadRecord(record, transaction);
        });
    },

    deleteOrUnloadRecord: function(record, transaction) {
        var deleteMethod = this.get('deleteMethod');
        if (deleteMethod === 'delete') {
            transaction.add(record);
            record.deleteRecord();
        }
        else if (deleteMethod === 'unload') {
            var store = this.get('store');
            store.unloadRecord(record);
        }
    }
});
```

Note that you can specify via `deleteMethod` whether or not you want to send the `DELETE` requests to your API. If your back-end is configured to delete dependent records automatically, then you will want to use the default.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sAmJ8/) that shows it in action.

Comment: Hey, this looks extremely OK! Although I think `ember-data` should support something like that in core. Thanks for such a detailed explanation, dude!

Comment: I agree. Ember Data is missing some key features but it's still very young and improving very quickly.

Comment: Ember Data no longer supports transactions, so the code above will need to be modified to work with recent builds.

Answer (score 3):

A quick-and-dirty way would be to add the following to your user model

```
destroyRecord: ->
  @get('comments').invoke('unloadRecord')
  @_super()
```

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the answer of @ahmacleod to work with `ember-cli 2.13.1` and `ember-data 2.13.0`. I had an issue with nested relationships and the fact that after deleting an entity from the database its id was reused. This lead to conflicts with remnants in the ember-data model.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
    dependentRelationships: null,

    destroyRecord: function() {
        this.deleteDependentRelationships();

        return this._super()
        .then(function (model) {
            model.unloadRecord();

            return model;
        });
    },

    unloadRecord: function() {
        this.deleteDependentRelationships();

        this._super();
    },

    deleteDependentRelationships: function() {
        var self = this;
        var fields = Ember.get(this.constructor, 'fields');

        this.get('dependentRelationships').forEach(function(name) {
            self.deleteRelationship(name);
        });
    },

    deleteRelationship (name) {
        var self = this;
        self.get(name).then(function (records) {
            if (!records) {
                return;
            }

            var reset = [];
            if (!Ember.isArray(records)) {
                records = [records];
                reset = null;
            }

            records.forEach(function(record) {
                if (record) {
                    record.unloadRecord();
                }
            });

            self.set(name, reset);
        });
    },
});
```

Eventually, I had to set the relationship to `[]` (hasMany) or `null` (belongsTo). Else I would have run into the following error message:

`Assertion Failed: You cannot update the id index of an InternalModel once set. Attempted to update <id>.`

Maybe this is helpful for somebody else.