# How to delete all records associated with an ember model without clearing local Storage?

Tags: ember.js, local-storage, ember-data, ember-model

I have extended the program given in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709381/how-to-delete-ember-data-record-by-its-id) to have a program that deletes all the records all at once. However, the deletion happens only in batches and does not delete everything all at once.

Here is a snippet of the function I am using in this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/uYArAXa/1/).

```
deleteAllOrg: function(){
  this.get('store').findAll('org').then(function(record){
    record.forEach(function(rec) {
        console.log("Deleting ", rec.get('id'));
        rec.deleteRecord();
        rec.save();
    });
    record.save();
  });
}
```

Any idea how the program can be modified such that all records can be deleted at once?

I have also  tried model.destroy() and model.invoke('deleteRecords') but they don't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Calling `deleteRecord()` within `forEach` will break the loop. You can fix it by wrapping the delete code in an `Ember.run.once` function like this:

```
  this.get('store').findAll('org').then(function(record){
     record.content.forEach(function(rec) {
        Ember.run.once(this, function() {
           rec.deleteRecord();
           rec.save();
        });
     }, this);
  });
```

See [this jsBin](http://jsbin.com/EnOxOPa/1).

Comment: Nowadays you can call `this.get('store').findAll('org').invoke('destroyRecord')` to delete them all.

Comment: @Jacob, That actually doesn't work. Invoke uses the same forEach function.

Comment: @NicholasJohn16: You are right, you need to add `coalesceFindRequests: true` to the RESTAdapter to let it work. See: http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/08/18/ember-data-1-0-beta-9-released.html#toc_coalescing-find-requests

Comment: @JacobvanLingen `this.get('store').findAll('org').invoke('destroyRecord')` send a GET request to /orgs instead of DELETE